# Android viewflipper with multiple images and radiobuttons on it with swipe images

Tags: android, viewflipper

I am new to android here i have to achieve the view flipper with multiple image radiobuttons on it like jabong home screen How can i acheive it.Can any one please help me out with examples.The following screen is examples of my app screen.

[image]